# How to place ImageViews on top of another ImageView?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, imageview

I have a very simple problem. I would like to place ImageViews on top of this image of a guitar fret board so I can make a simple tablature program not unlike songsterr but very simple.

Here is what the view currently looks like.

[Guitar Fretboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayfpu.png)

and here is the code for that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="top"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fretboardView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="777dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/fretboard" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is an example of what I would like it to look like.

[With frets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q33sa.png)

What I tried to do was make my root layout the relative layout and just place them where I want but when I drag another ImageView into my view, it just places it off screen. Thank you to those who take the time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't require nesting a `RelativeLayout` inside a `ConstraintLayout`. You will also likely want your `ScrollView` as the top level layout, with your root layout inside the `ScrollView`. Also, what is your intention with having a `HorizontalScrollView` nested within the `ScrollView`? Are you needing the view to scroll both vertically and horizontally?

Within a `ConstraintLayout` you can layout any views relative to each other or the parent `ConstraintLayout` view. This includes having some child views on top of other child views.

Another option would be to use a `FrameLayout`, which wraps the content of the background `ImageView`. Then use a `LinearLayout` to place the smaller views on top. For example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fretboardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fretboard" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dot2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/dot" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

You may also need to use another vertical orientation `LinearLayout` to layout the dots along the strings in a fret. For example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fretboardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fretboard" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dot" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dot" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

You'll also need to add spaces where you don't want dots. For example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fretboardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fretboard" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dot" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dot_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dot" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dot_size" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dot_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dot" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Where `@dimen/dot_size` is defined as the size of one of the dots.

There are several variations using different layout types you could use. `ConstraintLayout` has the advantage of requiring only a single root `ViewGroup`. But it might be easier to conceptualize and build the layout using the `LinearLayout`s similar to my examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I only need to scroll the fretboard horizontally not vertically but I couldn't disable the vertical. When I try your code I get very close but I can't seem to position the dots exactly https://gyazo.com/dbf106c8d381f6b2ed630dba55b67e76 here is a screen shot.

Comment: You may want to set the gravity on both the fret board image and the outer `LinearLayout`, probably `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`. You could also add top padding to the first `LinearLayout` with `android:paddingTop="50dp"`, however much needed such that it lines up with the fret board image. But the padding solution might not work for different screen sizes.

Comment: Hey thanks! That is much closer now with the gravity attribute. https://gyazo.com/2aa3d00323d3483910c753957f176e88 I will mark this as a solution but I might make another to ask about how to do it for different screen sizes. Thank you.